# Get check box state when state changed foundation

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, checkboxlist

How to get the check box state when it is changed. I am using zurb foundation

```
<label for="checkbox3"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="chk[2]"></input>
   <span class="custom checkbox" onclick="toggleState(2)"></span>
   Check Box 1
</label>
```

But in function  state prior to clicked is shown.
How should i get the latest value
Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove the onclick="toggleState(2)" and try some jquery code similar to:

```
$('#checkbox2').on('change', function() {
  console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Also, you should change your label to `<label for="checkbox2">` rather than `<label for="checkbox3">` as an element with the id checkbox3 doesn't exist.

It would also help if you could mention what version of Foundation you are using.